# How do I take a backup of my Master Boot Record (MBR) and Partition Table (PT)?

Tags: partitioning, backup, mbr, boot-partition

I'd like to know how to:

1. [take a backup](https://askubuntu.com/a/957868/344926)
2. [do a restore](https://askubuntu.com/a/960656/344926)

of all the MBRs and all the PTs of all my disks to a file so I can easily back them up using `rsync` or a comparable program.

Comment: I do not believe in backing up MBR as it is too easy to reinstall boot loader. And if you change partition table then part of MBR is invalid. You can backup MBR as per Fabby's post. But 512 includes primary part of the partition table. If you use 446 then that is the boot loader code part without MBR. I prefer to run Boot-Repair's report or bootinfoscript which I run as part of rsync copy to document entire configuration. Updated fork  as original bootinfoscript does not seem to be maintained
https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript and I have flash drive with Ubuntu to restore MBR.

Comment: Unusually, I disagree with oldfred on this one. I've seen many posts from people who've lost partitions because of accidentally overwriting the first few sectors of a hard disk or because of fumble-fingering a command involving a partitioning tool. Having a backup of the partition table in such a case will enable easily restoring partitions that haven't been damaged. Without a backup, you'll be left using TestDisk. Although TestDisk is a useful tool, it's not 100% reliable; I'd rather have a backup than have to rely on TestDisk.

Comment: @oldfred i personally take full System back-ups including the MBR, but I don't take them often enough and had a superblock error a few weeks ago.  No biggie as parted rescue solved it, but now I have a copy of the MBR and PT of all my disks on the other disks... (feels good that a genius like Mr. rEFInd agrees with me though!)  **I'm :-) :-) :-)**

Comment: Just to parse my response hopefully a bit more clearly. MBR is two parts boot code & partition table. I have in past backed up partition table, and did rely more on bootinfoscripts text output of partition table so I could totally rebuild it. But based on Rod Smith's recommendation back in 2010 I now am totally converted to gpt. I still have text output, but gpt has backup partition table which is a bit more reliable than the old MBR(msdos) partition table.  For boot part of MBR, it just is easier to reinstall grub. And if UEFI back up ESP - efi system partition. So yes backup partition table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hah, that's pretty easy:

1. create a directory `/sysbackup`:

   ```
   mkdir /sysbackup
   ```
2. copy the following script in an editor:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # This script saves the well-known (last good) partition table entries to a text file 
   # and the MBR to a binary file for all live disks on the system.
   #
   # Copyright (c) Fabby 2017
   #
   # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under 
   # the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software 
   # Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later 
   # version.
   #
   # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
   # but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY 
   # or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. 
   # IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
   # DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, 
   # TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR 
   # THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. 
   # See the GNU General Public License for more details.
   #
   # You DID NOT receive a copy of the GNU General Public License along with 
   # this program as the license is bigger then this program.
   # Therefore, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ for more details.
   #
   # This script should be run at the /etc/rc.local or systemd equivalent point in time
   #
   for szDisk in /dev/?d?; 
   do
     sfdisk --dump "$szDisk" > /sysbackup/PartBackup-"$(hostname)-${szDisk//\//-}""$(date +"%F-%H%M%S%N")"".txt"
     dd if="$szDisk" of=/sysbackup/MBRBackup-"$(hostname)-${szDisk//\//-}""$(date +"%F-%H%M%S%N")"".bck" bs=512 count=1
   done;
   ```
3. save it in `/usr/local/bin` (E.g. as `mbr-pt-bck`)
4. `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mbr-pt-bck`
5. execute it using `sudo mbr-pt-bck`
6. Ensure `/sysbackup/` is included in your `rsync` (or comparable) command.

Alternatively,

- put the above script in `/etc/rc.local` or equivalent systemd and auto-execute it at every boot.
- include it in your pre-backup script

Comment: The fastest disks don't use `/dev/sdX` rather `/dev/nvme...`. Still +1 for 10 times more comments than the five lines of code :D

Comment: `md` is an alias for `mkdir`, eh?

Comment: @Fabby - thank you! I have saved the script file without an extension. But how to I run it? i typed in the name of the script in the terminal (after navigating to the right directory) but it still won't execute

Comment: `./script` @BKSpurgeon (Sorry, missed your July question )

Answer (score 1):

To restore any of the above is pretty easy too:

#### MBR:

```
dd if=/sysbackup/MBRBackup-szHostName-dev-sda.bck of=/dev/sda  bs=512 count=1
```

#### PT:

First to a `cat /sysbackup/PartBackup-szHostName-dev-sda.txt`

```
Disk label type: msdos
Minor    Start       End     Type      Filesystem  Flags
1          0.031   8056.032  primary   ext3
```

Then just do a:

```
parted /dev/sda rescue
```

and you'll get the parted rescue prompt, where you fill in the data from the above `cat`

```
Start? 0
End? 8056
Information: A ext3 primary partition was found at 0.031MB ->
8056.030MB.  Do you want to add it to the partition table?
Yes/No/Cancel? y
```